# How to make table columns' height and width equal

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This is the code. I tried to it with colgroup

```
<col style="width: 100px; height:100px;">
```

but didn't work. This is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ouur4g75/) of the table I want every column to be `100px` high and `100px` wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```css
body{
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
}

.header {
 font-size: 60px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

td{               /* ADDED */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="25px"> 
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="header"><span>SoftUni LIFE</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><span>Google</span></td>
    <td colspan="2">GitHub</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FB</td>
    <td>GMail</td>
    <td>YouTube</td>
    <td>2048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Food</td>
    <td colspan="2">Game</td>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Social Life</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sleep</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Beer></td>
    <td>WC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I just added the last css rule to set height and width of `td` elements.

This will have every `td` width and height set to `100px`, and those who have colspan will have the number of columns spanned multiplied with default (100px) width, it's the same with rowspan.